# Pull text from another cell into an INDIRECT formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm using the INDIRECT formula to extract data from specific cells in hundreds of different sheets. In column B, I've listed all of the cells I need data from, and the worksheet names are in row 6. Any suggestions on how to exract the cell number from column B?

I've tried using text strings and the CONCATENATE function, but because of the quotations, I'm getting a reference error.

```
=INDIRECT("'"&$C$6&"'!M8")
```

I want to pull data from cell M8 in every sheet, but "M8" is listed in cell B2.

Comment: `=INDIRECT("'"&$C$6&"'!"&B2)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
=INDIRECT("'"&$C$6&"'!"&B2)
```

You have to use the `Value` in cell B2.

Comment: Perfect, that worked. Thank you! I was trying to reference the cell inside of the quotations, after the exclamation mark.

Comment: @AmberN If that worked for you, you can flag it as the Answer by clicking the check mark left of the post (under the up/down arrows).

Comment: @BruceWayne Thanks Bruce, I saw your comment go right as I was submitting :)